# Call parent view's javascript function from partial view's javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function say `Check()` in parent view, and this parent view has one partial view called child. And this child view have one java script function in it, which will triggered after a anchor tag click and that in turn will call my parent view's `Check()` function.

So what i need is to call parent view's `Check()` function from this partial view's function. **simply putting parent view's script function in partial view is not calling `Check()`**. How do i do it, Please correct me on this

This is what i have done so far,

My **partial view** script function looks like

```
function supp_checkAndReset(elem) {
    var currentSelected = $(elem).attr('id');
    $('.supp_panelfilterresultholder span[title="' + currentSelected + '"]').remove();
    $('.supp_panelfiltersuggestion input[value="' + currentSelected + '"]').prop('checked', false);

    Check();
 }
```

and my **parent view** script function comes under the script tag looks like

```
 function Check() {
        var supp_fullCheckList = $("#supp_filterWithThis").val();
        var practice_fullCheckList = $("#practice_filterWithThis").val();
        var county_fullCheckList = $("#county_filterWithThis").val();
        var state_fullCheckList = $("#state_filterWithThis").val();

        var ratebase_sliderValue = $("#ratebase_sliderValue").val();
        var clientRating_sliderValue = $("#clientRating_sliderValue").val();
        var panelRating_sliderValue = $("#panelRating_sliderValue").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchResultBasedOnFilters", "SearchResult")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                supp_fullCheckList: supp_fullCheckList, practice_fullCheckList: practice_fullCheckList, county_fullCheckList: county_fullCheckList,
                state_fullCheckList: state_fullCheckList, ratebase_sliderValue: ratebase_sliderValue, clientRating_sliderValue: clientRating_sliderValue, panelRating_sliderValue: panelRating_sliderValue
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var totRecordCount = $('#RecordTotalCount').val();

                $('#TotRecordCount').html(totRecordCount);

                $('#searchArea').html('');
                $('#searchArea').html(response);
            },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + " : " + error);
        }});
    }
```

Comment: check console for errors using dev tools

Comment: I checked and it showing Check is not defined

Comment: better way is to add js in seperate js file and include it in master layout

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i did the same as you said, but now i am getting console error as "Illegal characters in path"

Comment: A partial view should never contain a script. Include it in the main view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for that info, why it is not possible to include script in partial view? i already added some in my partial view and its working fine in it. The only thing its not working is this function call from child to parent.

Comment: It is possible but not recommended. SO has numerous questions about why code is failing when scripts are inside partials. One potential problem is loading a partial multiple times thereby duplicating the script - its just no good practice. How are you actually calling the `supp_checkAndReset()` function?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you said will be right, But i dont have any duplicate scripts in my view. When i checked here i found a simple mistake but that caused this issue. The reason for not calling or not getting my parent function was, i have put Cehck() function inside the docuement ready tag of my parent view. When i put it outside, now i am getting call from my child. I think i fugred out the problem. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Keep both javascript functions `supp_checkAndReset(elem)` and `Check()` in the main view i.e., the parent view. So it will then be accessible from both the view and the partial view.

It should be like this in the **parent view**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function supp_checkAndReset(elem) {
var currentSelected = $(elem).attr('id');
$('.supp_panelfilterresultholder span[title="' + currentSelected + '"]').remove();
$('.supp_panelfiltersuggestion input[value="' + currentSelected + '"]').prop('checked', false);

Check();
}
 function Check() {
    var supp_fullCheckList = $("#supp_filterWithThis").val();
    var practice_fullCheckList = $("#practice_filterWithThis").val();
    var county_fullCheckList = $("#county_filterWithThis").val();
    var state_fullCheckList = $("#state_filterWithThis").val();

    var ratebase_sliderValue = $("#ratebase_sliderValue").val();
    var clientRating_sliderValue = $("#clientRating_sliderValue").val();
    var panelRating_sliderValue = $("#panelRating_sliderValue").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchResultBasedOnFilters", "SearchResult")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            supp_fullCheckList: supp_fullCheckList, practice_fullCheckList: practice_fullCheckList, county_fullCheckList: county_fullCheckList,
            state_fullCheckList: state_fullCheckList, ratebase_sliderValue: ratebase_sliderValue, clientRating_sliderValue: clientRating_sliderValue, panelRating_sliderValue: panelRating_sliderValue
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var totRecordCount = $('#RecordTotalCount').val();

            $('#TotRecordCount').html(totRecordCount);

            $('#searchArea').html('');
            $('#searchArea').html(response);
        },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + " : " + error);
    }});
}
```

Comment: Actually nothing happening

Comment: Clean the solution,cookies and try.

Comment: I figured out the issue The reason for not calling or not getting my parent function was, i have put Cehck() function inside the docuement ready tag of my parent view. When i put it outside, now i am getting call from my child. Thanks alot for your help.